# How to define a multiline wstring with content from another file

Tags: c++

I would like to define the content of a file in a `wstring`, so I can print it with an `ofstream` later on.

Example:

```
// Working
std::wstring file_content=L"€";
```

```
// Working
file_content=L"€"
L"€"
L"€";
```

```
// NOT Working
file_content=L"€"
L"€""
L"€";
```

```
// Working
file_content=LR"SOMETHING(multiline
with
no
issues)SOMETHING";
```

For some reason, the last solution is not working for me WHEN I paste in the file content (Multibyte).

Errors:

> E0065 expected a ';'

> E2452 ending delimiter for raw string not found

[image]

Comment: You need to escape the extra quote with a backslash. `L"Extra Quote > \" <"`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I updated the post with better information.

Comment: Why are you storing *binary* data in a **wide** string? Why are you use a string at all? This is not a good use of strings. You should be storing the data in a binary resource in the exe instead, and then extract that resource at runtime when needed. Refer to your compiler's documentation for how to work with resources.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Because the file also contains raw string data that I would like to modify during runtime.

Comment: That doesn't change what I said. Putting your *binary* data into a *wide* string literal is a very bad choice. Put it into a resource instead, and if you need to make modifications to it then you can load the resource into a string when needed (preferably a *narrow* string, as there is no good reason to ever load binary data into a *wide* string)

Comment: @RemyLebeau Awesome, thanks for helping me out! I will save the raw binary data in a .rc file instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to *escape* double-quote characters inside of a string literal, eg:

```
// Working
file_content=L"€"
L"€\"" // <--
L"€";
```

Alternatively, use a [*raw* string literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) instead, which does not require its characters to be escaped, eg:

```
// Working
file_content=L"€"
LR"(€")" // <--
L"€";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
std::wstring file_content=LR"SOMETHING(
€
€"
€
)SOMETHING";
```

Here, `SOMETHING` is something not found in the string and not required but it enables you to use `"` inside the multiline string literal without having to escape it.

Comment: Note that your resulting string will contain extra line break characters that are not in the OP's example strings. Whitespace (including line breaks) between literals is ignored. Whitespace inside a literal is not.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I updated the post with better information.